# Convert character from a string w/ another character from a database

Tags: arrays, c, char

I'm making a character converter in C.

It's very simple logically: You type a character and the program detects it and replaces it with the other character associated with it in a new string.

During the project, I've got two problems by now:

```c
void ReadString()
{
    scanf("%s", inpString);
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(inpString);  i++)
    {
        ConvertChars(inpString);
    }
    
    PrintString();
}
    
void ConvertChars(char *convertedChars[])
{
    if(strpbrk(convertedChars, "ཀ"))
    {
        strcpy(outString, "!");
    }
    
    if(strpbrk(convertedChars, "ཁ"))
    {
        strcpy(outString, "\"");
    }
    
}
```

1. Whenever I type `"ཀ"` or `"ཁ"`, the output is always the same (the `"` for `"ཁ"`).
2. For some reason, the `for` loop doesn't seems to work, because it never outputs two or more characters converted, only one (despite there being two or more characters entered in the `inpString`).

What could be causing these problems?

Comment: That code should give you a lot of warnings about mismatching types. And the `ReadString` function doesn't make sense. Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: `strpbrk` expects a byte-delimited input, but this is a multi-byte character (in UTF-8, I assume.)

Comment: `ConvertChars()` expects an array of `char*` pointers, but it should take a single `char*` instead. But your `for` loop passes in the same `char*` pointer over and over to `ConvertChars()`. You should increment the `inpString` pointer on each iteration (ie `inpString+i`), or else you should change `ConvertChars()` to take in a single `char` instead of a `char*` pointer. Either way, `ConvertChars()` is not copying non-replaced characters into `outString`

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't specify an encoding of `ཀ` or `ཁ`, so it's open-ended what your computer means by this. However, it is probably UTF-8, representing unicode code point `U+0F40` by `e0 bd 80` and `U+0F41` by `e0 bd 81`. Even if you fixed the logic errors, `strpbrk` splits up byte-by-byte, and is therefore unsuited for multi-byte sequences.

If you need to translate certain characters from UTF-8, one way to do it is a state machine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buf[1024], out[sizeof buf];
    size_t n;
    enum { UTF_ONE_BYTE, UTF_TWO_BYTES, UTF_THREE_BYTES } state = UTF_ONE_BYTE;
    do {
        n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof buf, stdin);
        size_t o = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            const unsigned char cursor = buf[i];
            switch(state) {
            case UTF_ONE_BYTE:
                switch(cursor) {
                case 0xe0: state = UTF_TWO_BYTES; break; /* May be translated? */
                default: out[o++] = cursor; break;
                }
                break;
            case UTF_TWO_BYTES:
                switch(cursor) {
                case 0xbd: state = UTF_THREE_BYTES; break;
                default: /* Nope, catch up. */
                    out[o++] = 0xe0; out[o++] = cursor; state = UTF_ONE_BYTE; break;
                }
                break;
            case UTF_THREE_BYTES:
                switch(cursor) {
                case 0x80: out[o++] = '!'; break;
                case 0x81: out[o++] = '\"'; break;
                default: /* Not a translated character. */
                    out[o++] = 0xe0; out[o++] = 0xbd; out[o++] = cursor; break;
                }
                state = UTF_ONE_BYTE; break;
            }
        }
        fwrite(out, 1, o, stdout);
    } while(n == sizeof buf);
    return ferror(stdin) ? (perror("stdin"), EXIT_FAILURE) : EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can ignore all the other symbols because this assumes that this is valid UTF-8. See the [details on how UTF-8 works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).